# Variables are not defined and indentation errors

Tags: python

i am very new to python, I am writing a code to create a plot graph between gender in compared to days of the week, i do not know what's wrong with it as nothing results and having error of not defining the variable 'gender'

Note: i am using python 3

```
import calendar
def gender_perday_analysis(filename, gender):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        Reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)

        week_days = 0
        Female_count = []
        Male_count = []

        for row in Reader:
            if row['gender'] == 'Female':
                if row['day_of_week'] == 'Sunday':
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
                elif row['day_of_week'] == 'Monday':
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
                elif row['day_of_week'] == 'Tuesday':
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
                elif row['day_of_week'] == 'Wednesday':
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
                elif row['day_of_week'] == 'Thursday':
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
                elif row['day_of_week'] == 'Friday':
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
                else:
                    week_days+= 1
                    Female_count.append(week_days)
            else:
                week_days+= 1
                Male_count.append(week_days)

        return Male_count, Female_count


Chicago = './data/Chicago-2016-Summary.csv'
result2 = gender_perday_analysis(Chicago, 'gender')
print(result2)
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do with your current code-sample: Your argument `gender` of the function `gender_perday_analysis` doesn't get used anywhere in your function and you have a lot of IF-statements for every day of the week, but in every case, you then do the exact same action (and thus outcome).

Comment: Can you include the error in your post along with the traceback?  Off-hand it looks like something is missing in your post.  I suspect what you may actually be seeing is a keyword error... perhaps the data doesn't contain a column named 'gender'.  As written, the code runs--though it's not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
if row['gender'] == 'Female':
```

You were passing a string of `'gender'` in, and not the variable `gender`. Correct one below:

```
if row[gender] == 'Female':
```

Answer (score 1):

import csv, can help
but add an error

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your file is actually not reading what you think is required. It could be an error with reading the file. It would be helpful if you could add the exact errors given by your IDE. To test if its a problem with reading the file. Add this statement

```
for row in Reader:
       print(row)
```

Further , you can try using Pandas for reading and analyzing files as it makes things more easier.